# Grabbing specific recent changes from mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I am quite new to wikis but I would like to know if it is possible to basically grab the newest (top) recent change of each page and put it in some kind of feed or any useable format i.e. a list of every page's most recent change.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) to retrieve this data. Try it out, if you run into trouble, come back and we might be able to help : )